# UnsupportedClassVersionError with SonarQube Ant Task after Update to 5.1.1

Tags: ant, jenkins, sonarqube

I updated my SonarQube Installation from 4.0 to 5.1.1 exactly (i swear) like written [in the Upgrade Document](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading)

The Application runs... all fine...

Only the Ant Tasks doesn't work...

I got the [Sonar Ant Jar in Version 2.2](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+SonarQube+Ant+Task) **NOT THE VERSION 2.3** (you can see the [Compatibility Matrix here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code#AnalyzingSourceCode-CompatibilityMatrix))

My Ant Task looks like

```
<target name="sonar_apak">
 <property name="sonar.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[server]/SonarCube;SelectMethod=Cursor" />
 <property name="sonar.jdbc.username" value="XX" />
 <property name="sonar.jdbc.password" value="XX" />


 <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="XX" />
 <property name="sonar.projectName" value="XX" />
 <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="${jenkins.apak.version}.${jenkins.build.version}" />
 <property name="sonar.language" value="js" />
 <property name="sonar.sources" value="${web.docbase.dir}\api" />
 <property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

 <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="c:/Ant/extras/sonar-ant-task-*.jar" />
 </taskdef>
 <!-- Execute Sonar -->
 <sonar:sonar />
</target>
```

In the Sonar wrapper.conf is
    wrapper.java.command=java

So my

```
java -version
```

prints out

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

When I run the task on the console with

```
ant sonar_apak
```

this is the output

```
sonar_apak:
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
[sonar:sonar] SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.2
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/C:/Ant/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Default locale: "de_DE", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Work directory: d:\.jenkins\workspace\APAK\.sonar
[sonar:sonar] INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1.1

BUILD FAILED
d:\.jenkins\workspace\APAK\build.xml:106: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/api/utils/SonarException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:94)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1603)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:85)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:53)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:48)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Major.minor 51.0 is java7, so 1.8 jvm should process that without any problems. Do you also have any other java versions installed in your machine that ant may be founding them? Try to do `<echo message="${java.version}"/>` in your ant file just to see what version is ant using.

Comment: Jenkins may be using an older version of Java. As @pabrantes suggests, echo what `${java.version}` is.

Answer (score 1):

There was set an JAVA_HOME variable that pointed to an veeery old version.

Thanks for the hint!